# .gif Images background blinks when run via kivyLauncher however runs perfectly fine in windows

Tags: python, gif, kivy

Problem is that I need to show a .gif animated image on a button . It runs fine and behaves as expected when run on windows , however when executed by kivy launcher on android samsung s3 the background of .gif blinks . Does anyone have any idea why is that so ?

Is it problem with kivy launcher ?

Also if i use .zip images in palce of .gif it works fine on both windows and android .

See sample code on .github :
[Code](https://gist.github.com/PaarthBatra/11164900)

I asked this question earlier also but Really couldnt find out if this is the problem with kivy Launcher or .gif file because image works as desired on windows ?  . See link here
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23055596/gif-image-as-source-runs-nicely-in-windows-kivy-program-running-via-kivy-laun)

Update : I am using kivy launcher which is updated to work with latest 1.8.0 and is the latest one

Comment: Your .gif has a transparent background, replace it with one that's not transparent.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know which version of kivy launcher you are using but you can build your own version of it using the following instructions::

Python-for-android compiled with:

```
./distribute.sh -m "sqlite3 openssl pyopenssl lxml audiostream cymunk ffmpeg pil pyjnius twisted kivy"
```

Then go to dist/default, edit the blacklist.txt and remove all the sqlite3 references.

Then build the launcher with:

```
./build.py --package org.kivy.pygame --name "Kivy Launcher" --version 1.6.0.0 --launcher --permission INTERNET --permission BLUETOOTH --icon templates/launcher-icon.png --presplash templates/launcher-presplash.jpg release
```

Better yet just build your own apk of your app using buildozer http://github.com/kivy/buildozer